# How do i input an If statement on to my program using JOption.pane?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, joptionpane, jcreator

Hi i'm a newbie at programming, i'm having a bit of a trouble by adding an IF statement on to my program. I'm creating a Module Result calculator, the user inputs their result score for their exam and coursework, if the user achieves of 40% the program replies with  "Well done you've passed!" and if they get below 40% it replies back saying "Sorry but you failed!" however I've got the program to calculate the score but the message doesn't show on the GUI. 
![enter image description here][1]
I've created another one which is success, it shows the outcome on the console instead of the GUI.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me with the codes in this situation.

```
class GUI{
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String result1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Coursework Result:");
        String result2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Exam Result:");


        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(result1);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(result2);
        int avg =  (num1 + num2)/2;

        if (avg<40)
           System.out.println("Your Test Score:  "+avg+"% Sorry But You Failed!");
        else if(avg<=100)
           System.out.println("Your Test Score:  "+avg+"% Well Done, You Passed!");
}
}
```

Comment: So no message appears at all? I suppose this would maybe mean that `avg` is not satisfying the condition for being `<40` or `<= 100`. Does the program definitely terminate? Also, to aid consistency, try both reading and storing your results as `int`s.

Comment: The message appears, Enter exam then coursework, it just doesn't show the end result on the GUI.

Comment: If you put a message at the end, just saying `System.out.println("Finished!")`, does it get there?

Comment: Instead of that second `else if`, just write `if`. You seem to be performing an 'else' comparison with nothing since you're not using braces. Or instead, write this: 
`if (avg<40) {
    System.out.println("Your Test Score:  "+avg+"% Sorry But You Failed!");
} else {
System.out.println("Your Test Score:  "+avg+"% Well Done, You Passed!");
}`

Comment: Nope, the message did not appear on the GUI.

Comment: Nope, still didn't work. It just said Enter Coursework then Enter Exam and the box vanished.

Comment: The Result just appeard on the general output, but i would like the answer to appear on the GUI.

Comment: @Mohamed :) Well that's different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need to store your resulting message in a String:

```
String message = "";
if (avg<40)
    message = "Your Test Score:  "+avg+"% Sorry But You Failed!";

else if(avg<=100)
    message = "Your Test Score:  "+avg+"% Well Done, You Passed!";
```

Then you can display it using a JOptionPane using the following:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

What you are currently doing is printing out the result to the console using `System.out.println()`. This will not print it out to the GUI. The `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` method will display a dialog box with your resulting message.

Comment: Cheers Mate! Your a LIFESAVER!

Comment: How do i automatically make it start up on GUI when I press F5?

Comment: If you want your application to have an actual window as opposed to a pop up window you will need to look into JFrames.

Comment: You would need to look up how to use a JFrame, it would be much more involved than a simple statement to get this to work with an application GUI.